# How do I find out what class/selector I should use to style my element?

Tags: css, colors, css-selectors, nav, styling

The image below shows the coding of my Navbar. I'm wanting to style the 'book now' button by changing the color and adding a border around it, which i know how to do. The only part that i'm struggling on is identifying the class for selecting, only the 'book now' button.

Your help would be much appreciated!

[image: Navbar Color Change]

Comment: Please, see [ask] and then add your code as real code, not image.

Comment: Can you use nth-child select and apply css

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

`div[data-navlink-handle='book-now'] > a`

The essentially finds a div with an attribute `data-navlink-handle` that equals `book-now`.  Making an assumption here that the handle won't likely change, even if the text does.

Or possibly:
`div.navbar-item[data-navlink-handle='book-now'] > a`

Answer (score -1):

You do not have any unique identifiers on that element. You should consider adding id's. Or you could use the selector `a[innertext='Book Now']` or `div:contains('Book Now')` but that's kinda bad because your style will break if you change the content.